# Configure Vagrant and pureftpd with external access

Tags: ftp, vagrant

I am trying to setup a Vagrant VM (Ubuntu Lucid64) with pureftpd which I want to access from the host machine.

```rb
Vagrant::Config.run do |config|
  config.vm.define :my_vm do |conf|
    conf.vm.host_name = "my_vm"
    conf.vm.network :hostonly, "192.168.187.2"
    conf.vm.forward_port 22, 18722
    conf.vm.forward_port 21, 2121
    conf.vm.forward_port 22, 2122
    conf.vm.customize [ "modifyvm", :id, "--name", "my vm" ]
    conf.vm.box = "lucid64"
    conf.vm.boot_mode = :gui
    conf.ssh.max_tries = 150
    # Share the project root with the vagrant VMs
    conf.vm.share_folder("v-root", "/vagrant", File.expand_path(File.dirname(__FILE__)))
    # Set up passwordless ssh for root
    conf.vm.provision :shell, :inline =>
        "sudo mkdir -p /root/.ssh && sudo cat /home/vagrant/.ssh/authorized_keys >> /root/.ssh/authorized_keys"
  end

  # The url from where the 'config.vm.box' box will be fetched if it
  # doesn't already exist on the user's system.
  config.vm.box_url = "http://files.vagrantup.com/lucid64.box"

end
```

What I've got so far is the Vagrant machine working, pureftpd running and I can open an FTP connection. However, I cannot upload a file via FTP because I get the following error:

```
TYPE A
200 TYPE is now ASCII
PASV
227 Entering Passive Mode (10,0,2,15,156,170)
[Replacing site local address 10.0.2.15 with 127.0.0.1]
TYPE I
200 TYPE is now 8-bit binary
PASV
227 Entering Passive Mode (10,0,2,15,156,96)
[Replacing site local address 10.0.2.15 with 127.0.0.1]
NOOP
200 Zzz...
SITE CHMOD 644 /one/two_days_initial.xml
550 Could not change perms on /one/two_days_initial.xml
QUIT
221-Goodbye. You uploaded 0 and downloaded 0 kbytes.
221 Logout.
```

After reading a bit about FTP, I understand that I need to forward 2 ports to allow the ftp session to transfer Data, but my attempt (in my vagrant file) is not working.

I have double checked that the FTP user loggin in DOES have read/write privileges to the directory where I am trying to upload the file, but am still getting the mentioned error.

Has anyone configured a Vagrant and an FTP server (pureftp or other) so that it can accept FTP connections?

Comment: I don't really understand the use case. If you want to sync files, Why NOT use the virtualbox built-in shared folders or `nfs`. Even `sshfs` will work better than FTP. If you really prefer FTP, better to use bridged mode instead of default NAT.

Comment: An example use case is that you want to simulate a ftp server before doing anything live as it were.

Comment: As @knowledge_is_power said, the reason behind using an FTP server in vagrant is to test some FTP server settings in a VM test environment before deploying.

Comment: I think it might has to do with the filesystems (guest / host). Have you tried to point the PureFTPd to the internal FS (= not the NFS)? Where is currently your FTP root?